# Exporting degrees with decimal minutes in QGIS

Tags: qgis, export, csv, degrees-minutes-seconds, libreoffice

I've been asked to export some coordinates (from WGS84 zone 31N to WGS84) in degrees with decimal minutes.

I've been manipulating an output СІМ in LibreOffice Сalc for some while & it seems terribly convoluted (extracting parts of strings & recombining them etc.). Perfect breeding ground for errors. Just wondered if anyone had a better way?

Comment: Maybe related: [How to get latitude /longitude in Degree Minute Second (DMS) using QGIS field calculator?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/28655/how-to-get-latitude-longitude-in-degree-minute-second-dms-using-qgis-field-ca)